# Airflow: changing the crontab time for a DAG in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG that has been running everyday at 3:00, it ran OK for the past few weeks.

I've updated the date to run now at 7:00, but apparently for the last 2 days it didn't run. I can see the tasks for those two days with the status 'running' (in green), but no command is triggered.

Does one needs to do something more to change de running time of a DAG ?

I know that in the past one way to solve this was to clean in the meta-database the tasks for this DAG, and update the start_date, but I would rather avoid doing this again.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To schedule a dag, Airflow just looks for the last `execution date` and sum the `schedule interval`. If this time has expired it will run the dag. You cannot simple update the start date. 
A simple way to do this is edit your `start date` and `schedule interval`, rename your dag (e.g. xxxx_v2.py) and redeploy it.

Comment: Is there a larger discussion about the need to rename DAGs in order to reflect updated metadata? If so, can someone link to it please?

Comment: I couldn't find discussion but it is mentioned in pitfalls
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls

Comment: The Common Pitfalls page moved: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62694614

Comment: A GitHub discussion about changing `schedule_interval` of an Airflow DAG can be found here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/25304.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution to renaming the DAG is to edit the `execution_date` of all prior task instances and DAG runs of the DAG in the database. The tables to alter are `task_instance` and `dag_run` respectively.

One of the downsides of this approach is that you will lose the ability to browse logs of completed tasks through the webserver.

Comment: Hmm, but the main appeal of not renaming the DAG is to keep the logs, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

David,
 1. You can also delete the dag via Experimental REST API. [deleting a DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651783/airflow-how-to-delete-a-dag)
 2. Change the desired `start_date`.
 3. And add the same DAG back.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same dag. After modifying `schedule_interval`, you need to mark the previous job as succeeded via `airflow backfill -m` command.