# How delete broken DAG from airflow list?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

in airflow show information about Broken DAG

```
Broken DAG: [/data/airflow/dags/copy_from_Oracle_to_MySQL.py] No module named Oracle_to_MySQL_plugin
```

I tried to move file with DAG copy_from_Oracle_to_MySQL.py from /data/airflow/dags.

But airflow showing information

```
Broken DAG: [/data/airflow/dags/copy_from_Oracle_to_MySQL.py] No module named Oracle_to_MySQL_plugin
```

What I must to do that information about Broken DAG clean from GUI?

Comment: To those finding answers, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375328/1776759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So removing the DAG file won't clean them all, you will need to delete all dag_id in your metadata DB then UI won't show them, you can find a list of tables here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1002.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you place Oracle_to_MySQL_plugin? Did you check is it in your pythonpath?