# Delete a DAG in google composer - Airflow UI

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I want to delete a DAG from the Airflow UI, that's not longer available in the `GCS/dags` folder.
I know that Airflow has a "new" way to remove dags from the DB using 
`airflow delete_dag my_dag_id` command, seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49683543/5318634

It seems that in composer airflow version the `delete_dag` command is not yet supported.

**Do not try this:**  I've also tried using `airflow resetdb` and the airflow UI died

Is there a way to delete the dags that are not currently in the `gs://BUCKET/dags/` folder ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created a DAG to cleanup UI. It reads `afDagID` from Airflow Variables

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators.mysql_operator import MySqlOperator
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

dag = DAG('ManageAirFlow', description='Deletes Airflow DAGs from backend: Uses vars-  afDagID',
      schedule_interval=None,
      start_date=datetime(2018, 3, 20), catchup=False)

DeleteXComOperator = MySqlOperator(
  task_id='delete-xcom-record-task',
  mysql_conn_id='airflow_db',
  sql="DELETE from xcom where dag_id='{}'".format(models.Variable.get('afDagID')),
  dag=dag)

DeleteTaskOperator = MySqlOperator(
  task_id='delete-task-record-task',
  mysql_conn_id='airflow_db',
  sql="DELETE from task_instance where dag_id='{}'".format(models.Variable.get('afDagID')),
  dag=dag)

DeleteSLAMissOperator = MySqlOperator(
  task_id='delete-sla-record-task',
  mysql_conn_id='airflow_db',
  sql="DELETE from sla_miss where dag_id='{}'".format(models.Variable.get('afDagID')),
  dag=dag)

DeleteLogOperator = MySqlOperator(
  task_id='delete-log-record-task',
  mysql_conn_id='airflow_db',
  sql="DELETE from log where dag_id='{}'".format(models.Variable.get('afDagID')),
  dag=dag)

DeleteJobOperator = MySqlOperator(
  task_id='delete-job-record-task',
  mysql_conn_id='airflow_db',
  sql="DELETE from job where dag_id='{}'".format(models.Variable.get('afDagID')),
  dag=dag)

DeleteDagRunOperator = MySqlOperator(
  task_id='delete-dag_run-record-task',
  mysql_conn_id='airflow_db',
  sql="DELETE from dag_run where dag_id='{}'".format(models.Variable.get('afDagID')),
  dag=dag)

DeleteDagOperator = MySqlOperator(
  task_id='delete-dag-record-task',
  mysql_conn_id='airflow_db',
  sql="DELETE from dag where dag_id='{}'".format(models.Variable.get('afDagID')),
  dag=dag)



DeleteXComOperator >> DeleteTaskOperator >> DeleteSLAMissOperator >> DeleteLogOperator >> DeleteJobOperator >> DeleteDagRunOperator >> DeleteDagOperator
```

Comment: @Josh
is this code still valid?
How do I define afDagID?
it gives me an error
KeyError: 'Variable afDagID does not exist'
thanks for the help

Comment: I am the editor not the answerer! @Bikram - any tips?

Answer (score 2):

As cloud composer is using the latest **stable** version i.e. `1.9.0`, the feature to delete dag is not available.

However,

There are few instructions in the docs to delete a dag as below:

```
 gcloud beta composer environments storage dags delete \
     --environment ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
     --location LOCATION \
     DAG_NAME.py
```

but unfortunately, this would not remove the DAG from the Airflow web interface.

More info: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/managing-dags#deleting_a_dag

Comment: do you know how to access to the cloud composer master?

Comment: Hey, sorry composer is a managed service hence you won't be able to access master. I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: @PabloA You can access it from "Google Kubernetes Engine", so visit GKE page on google cloud, find the cluster using compiser and click on "Connect"

Comment: doesn't this just go to GCS and delete the file? but the dag's remnants (history, state) still remain in Composer/Airflow?

Answer (score 0):

It will be take place in 2 steps:-
step1:-

First you have to delete **airflow_monitoring.py** file with command from storage bucket.

gcloud composer environments storage dags delete --environment viu-etl-prod-composer --location us-central1 airflow_monitoring.py

step 2:-
  click on red cross check as shown in picture.

[image]