# Airflow: Is there a way where I can trigger a job at 35th second, every minute using CRON expression?

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to trigger a shell script at 35th second, every minute. However, I see that airflow supports CRON from the minute level instead of the second level.

For example, the cron Expression

```
35 * * * *
```

triggers a job at every 35th minute in airflow.

Comment: I presume you mean `35 * * * *`, not `35****`.

Comment: Hi interesting, perhaps this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689072/airflow-dag-running-every-second-rather-than-every-minute

Comment: @KeithThompson Edited the expression to remove confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Airflow, but cron only supports 1-minute resolution.

You could use cron to invoke a job every minute and let the job sleep for 35 seconds:

```
* * * * * sleep 35 ; do_something
```