# How to delete definitely default DAGs in Airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Hello i am a new user of Airflow i have started the Airflow webserver and i want to run my own batch on it, and there is Airflow by defaults DAG.
I tried to delete them from GUI then i followed instruction to delete DAG from CLI as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651783/airflow-how-to-delete-a-dag) 
but the problem is that they reappear after a bit .
i already put the configuration of Airflow to False 
`load_examples = False` inside  `airflow.cfg` 
is there any solution to delete definitely every default DAG ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you change `load_examples = False` inside `airflow.cfg` restart your Airflow Webserver & Scheduler.

If your example DAGs have already run, you might have to run `airflow resetdb` if you are on Airflow <2 and run `airflow db reset` if you are on Airflow>2.0.

Comment: Did it but still the same situation

Comment: Run `airflow resetdb` and try again

Comment: if you are using airflow 2.0.1, this one will not work. Use instead: `airflow db reset`