# How to delete a DAG run in Apache Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I know there is a way to delete a DAG. But is it possible to delete a DAG run with a specific run_id? Something like:

`airflow delete_dag_run <dag_id> <run_id>`

Comment: One way to delete a DAG is to delete the dag file from the dags folder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651783/airflow-how-to-delete-a-dag

Comment: Anyone know how I can restart my accidentally deleted dag run

Answer (score 38):

To delete a DAG Run from the Airflow UI:

1. `Browse > "DAG Runs"`.
2. Select the DAG Runs you want to delete with the checkboxes on the left.
3. `"With selected" > Delete`.

Comment: I performed these 3 steps. But the deleted run spawned again after about 1 minute..

Answer (score 8):

You can also delete the "DAG Runs" from airflow database:

```sql
DELETE FROM dag_run
WHERE dag_id='my_dag_id' AND 
state='STATE_I_WANT_TO_DELETE'
```

Comment: is removing from db enought so airflow won't somehow take this runs out from memory/session whatever and execute?

Comment: @andilabs Thats a good question, my experience was airflow seemed to constantly check database so i did not see much delay there. Which makes sense to me because database is the final state of DAGs. And even if I change from airflow console UI I'm sure it will also update the database.

Comment: Shouldn't the task instances be deleted too?