# Modify the task schedule in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I want to modify the schedule of a task I created in a dags/ folder through the airflow UI. I can't find a way to modify the schedule through the UI. Can it be done or we can get it done only by modifying the python script ?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to change it is through the code. As it's part of the DAG definition (like tasks and dependencies), it appears to be difficult to be able to change it through the web interface.

Comment: Do we still need to **rename the DAG** (`dag_id`) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38028555/3679900) or have things improved?

Comment: @y2k-shubham No, there is no need to rename the DAG since at least v.1.9.x

Comment: @dorvak source? If you have a reliable source for this, we can update several questions on StackOverflow which currently say renaming is required. :)

Comment: Fwiw, I'm running Airflow v1.10 and was able to update the schedule interval without renaming the DAG