# Changing an Airflow's DAG end_date

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a set of DAGs that have run from `2011-01-01` to `2018-04-01` on a `@monthly` schedule. I've done this by setting the `start_date` and `end_date` on each of the dags. However, I've now realized I need it to run for one more month. I've updated the `end_date` to be `2018-05-01`, however updating this value has not triggered Airflow start another DagRun.

I've read [Airflow: changing the crontab time for a DAG in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294560/airflow-changing-the-crontab-time-for-a-dag-in-airflow?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but I do not want to change the Dag id because that would cause me to have to re-run all the months and I just want to add one additional month. Is this possible in Airflow?

Comment: Did you find a workaround? I am stuck with a very similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually trigger the dag after you have changed the `end_date` using CLI:

```sh
airflow trigger_dag [-h] [-sd SUBDIR] [-r RUN_ID] [-c CONF] [-e EXEC_DATE] dag_id
```

More info: https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#trigger_dag

Comment: Thanks, will try this. I have dozens of dags to trigger unfortunately. It'd be great to know the thing that is preventing Airflow from picking up these new dags and modify that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. `@monthly` is just a nicer way to say "0 0 1 * *" [1], If you have `end-date` set up,

> end_date: if specified, the scheduler won't go beyond this date[2]

You can try use `2018-05-02` instead.

[1]https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#dag-runs
[2]https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/models.py#L2164

Comment: This was the initial thing I tried, and it's not working unforutnately. Since I've already set an end date I seems like Airflow has stored that end date somewhere and is not backfilling any further.

Comment: Which version of airflow are you using? Also, since you are using @monthly can you try bump up `end_date` to `2018-06-01`

Comment: Version 1.9.0. Yes I did try to bump it to 2018-06-01 (not just 1 day)